# Eager loading sibling records without including self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

For serialization I want to include an array of sibling records which shares a common foreign key. I currently have the following:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :other_instances,
           source: :foo,
           class_name: 'Foo',
           foreign_key: 'event_id',
           primary_key: 'event_id'
```

When used in an include, it produces the following queries:

```
  Foo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "foo".* FROM "foo" WHERE "foo"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 21138]]
  Foo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "foo".* FROM "foo" WHERE "foo"."event_id" IN (11451)
```

This mostly works, but the issue is that `Foo.other_instances` includes itself. Is there any way to exclude that additional record in rails? The expected `includes` would look something like this:

```
  Foo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "foo".* FROM "foo" WHERE "foo"."event_id" IN (11451) AND "foo"."id" NOT IN (21138)
```

Update:

Attempting to make the condition instance dependent as in @spikermann's results in the following:

Code:

```
has_many :other_instances,
         source: :foo,
         class_name: 'Foo',
         foreign_key: 'event_id',
         primary_key: 'event_id', 
         ->(foo) { where.not(id: foo.id) }
```

Called with:

```
Foo.includes(:other_instances).find(21138)
```

Result:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The association scope 'other_instances' is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Preloading happens before the individual instances are created. This means that there is no instance being passed to the association scope. This will most likely result in broken or incorrect behavior. Joining, Preloading and eager loading of these associations is deprecated and will be removed in the future. (called from check_preloadable! at /home/jordan/prog/knotweed/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:362)
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a scope:

```
has_many :other_instances,
         source: :foo,
         class_name: 'Foo',
         foreign_key: 'event_id',
         primary_key: 'event_id', 
         ->(foo) { where.not(id: foo.id) }
```

Comment: No, not unless there is a way to eager load that which I am not aware of.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I had tried this previously and should have included that attempt in my original question. Updated with the issue I had with it.